# How can I get the error messages ,when there is a error happened in $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In "get_data" action ,there are some code like this:

```
def get_data
 if params[:p]=='1'
   raise "error 1"
 elsif params[:p]=='2'
   raise 'error 2'
 else
  return data
 end
end
```

in view:

```
<script>
 $.getJSON('/controller/get_data',function(){...})
</script>
```

so,when some error has raised,how can i get it!
Tks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to remember is.

getJson is just a thin wrapper for:

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {
    return jQuery.get(url, data, callback, "json"); 
},
```

Which in turn is a thin wrapper for get:

```
 get: function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omited
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = null;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
    });
},
```

Which simply boils down to a call to $.ajax, which has a simple failure and success handler.

So you could simply do:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    dataType: "json", 
    error: failureCallback
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail instructions,
and i use $.ajax method

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete with an error. This is an Ajax Event.